# O/RM Unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, junit4

I am doing some O/RM uni tests. Now here is the issue. 
1)To test delete(), I need to use insert()
2)To test insert() I need to use select()

Am I doing something wrong, because how else should I test methods independently?

Comment: I would recommend establishing a TEST DATABASE that is always initially populated with a known set of values. This will allow better testing of a large number operations - which should also cover transactions. Some tests, however, can be run within a single transaction to avoid time taken to "reset" the database. Some servers (like SQL Server or Firebird or SQLite) allow attaching instances directly to raw database files which works well with a FS copy + attach when needing to really mash at the data.

Comment: I do not think that will work, because unit tests are supposed to be run many times without changing anything, so if I have a pre-populated database and I delete something while testing delete, how to insert it back?
And even so how do I test insert(), without checking the output with select()?

Comment: There are two kinds of tests here - one is a "pure unit" that will, go from a known data state to a new database state and test it. The other are quasi "integration tests" that will test a series of operations. Using a TEST DATABASE makes the former super easy and allows a foundation for the latter - also the ORM doesn't need to test the ORM. The database state is *restored* between tests - for simple tests this can merely be transaction rollbacks. For tests that require transactions then this can still be a basis for a quick-setup based on various copy/clone techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You should use in-memory DB and make every test self-contained, without relying on pre-set data in DB (pseudo-code)

```
test should_insert_my_object_into_db() {
    //given
    MyObject original = givenNewMyObject();
    //when
    db.insert(original);
    //then
    MyObject copy = db.selectById(original.id);
    assertThat(copy).isEqualTo(original);
}

test should_delete_my_object_from_db() {
    //given
    MyObject original = givenMyObjectInsertedIntoDB();
    //when
    db.delete(original.id);
    //then
    MyObject copy = db.selectById(original.id);
    assertThat(copy).isNull();
}
```

Comment: I still did not understand how would I get givenMyObjectInsertedIntoDB  without inserting the data before that statement myself using the insert method?

Comment: @user1552879 you won't. but why would you try to avoid that?

Comment: I just thought I should be testing one method without using another.

Comment: I think, from the `should_delete_my_object_from_db` test point of view it does not matter how original got inserted into db - either by pre-populating db with existing data or by inserting it before hand. And since you already tested `insert` in `should_insert_my_object_into_db` test, why not use it to insert the data you need for any subsequent test? Don't focus on testing methods, test behaviours you expect from your classes.